# DXA 1.7 Java How To Get Multimedia Component Title

Tags: dxa-java, multimedia

I have a problem with multimedia components on my Java DXA 1.7 implementation, we have a Download list, which accepts multimedia components, by using WebComponentMetaFactory we read the component's metadata and try to read the title from there.

```
WebComponentMetaFactory wcf = new WebComponentMetaFactoryImpl(publicationId);
ComponentMeta componentMeta = wcf.getMeta(tcmIdComponent);
return componentMeta.getTitle();
```

After executing that code I will get as a result a string which seems to be the JSON path for the multimedia component

```
 tcd:pub[1262]/componentmeta[257020]
```

I can achieve obtaining the title of the component for other types but seems not to work for Multimedia components.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be duplicating
[DXA 1.7 Get Multimedia Component name](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17424/dxa-1-7-get-multimedia-component-name)
And also an issue has been raised 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/73